# Resize picture in a userForm to a percentage from the original image

Tags: excel, vba, image, size, userform

I'm trying to fit the size of my images inside a UserForm and I want to reduce the size of the images loaded to a certain percentage from the original size.
Currently an image looks like here:
[image: sample image]
The quality is decent but it's oversized.

I want to be able to do something like:
`Me.Image1.Picture.Height = 0.5 * Me.Image1.Picture.Height`

Images are loaded dynamically: first a snapshot of a range is taken, than it transforms into a shape, than it's exported to a folder and finally picked up from the folder by the UserForm.

As seen lower in the code, I've tried the following lines:
`Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = 3`
But this one stretches the image to fit UserForm image windows, which reduces image quality a lot.

`Me.Image1.Picture.Height = 300`
Do not seem to work, and I wasn't able to find a way to set the size manually.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Pict(n)
    Dim Ans As String
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim Pth As String
    Dim Pic As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Model")

    'MsgBox ws.Shapes.Count

    With ListBox1
        Set Pic = ws.Shapes(.List(n))
        'Set Pic = Sheets("CreateIndicTable").Shapes(1)

        Pic.Copy 'Picture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        Dim Strpath As String
        Strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp.jpg"
        '782 because it gives better image quality
        Set cht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(782, 782, Pic.Width, Pic.Height)
        cht.Name = "Indic_cht_0"

        'if absent, macro doesn't get enough time to analyse picture object
        Dim i, OpenForms
        For i = 1 To 3    ' Start loop.
                OpenForms = DoEvents    ' Yield to operating system.
        Next i

        cht.Select
        cht.Chart.Paste
        
        'MsgBox cht.Name
        'ws.ChartObjects("Indic_cht_0").Paste
        
        cht.Chart.Export Strpath
        cht.Delete
        Set cht = Nothing

        'Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
        'Me.Image1.Picture.Height = 300

        Me.Image1.PictureAlignment = fmPictureAlignmentTopLeft
        Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Strpath)
        'Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = 3
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did the answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The vba code will not resize the image inside the editor where you can design the user forms. Modifications to `image.height` and `.width` can only be seen while the user form is actually shown, for example by running `userForm1.show`.

### Solution 1 : Size of Image after loading

- Load the picture
- Set PictureSizeMode: `Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom`
- Set width and heigt as desired: `Me.Image1.Height = 100` and `Me.Image1.Width = 100`
- Show the user form

### Solution 2 : Scale chart before exporting

```
cht.Height = cht.Height / 2
cht.Width = cht.Width / 2
cht.Chart.Export Strpath
```

The two solutions will not look the same, since scaling the chart leaves the title and other text of the chart unchanged.